# Remove intermediate folder while performing aws s3 sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an S3 bucket structure as so:

```
foo/
├── bar/
│   └── baz/
│       ├── bar.xml
│       └── bar.csv
```

I'm performing this command to sync only the `bar.xml`:

```
aws s3 sync s3://foo/bar ./bar --exclude "*" --include "*.xml"
```

How can I get bar.xml into the current file directory in folder `bar/`? Currently, it is syncing as `/bar/baz/bar.xml`. How do I remove the intermediate `baz` folder and get it to sync as `/bar/bar.xml` in my current folder directory?

Answer (score 2):

Directories in the s3 are only logical naming of the files, not really a directory.
Having said that, `sync` always maintain the directory/path structure, and here, I believe you have to use `s3 mv` where the path can be modified.